# Проблема со шрифтом pillow, heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pillow

Как я понял, heroku не может найти шрифт. Когда запускал код на своем пк, все хорошо работало, а здесь выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vkbottle/dispatch/base.py", line 22, in route
await view.handle_event(event, ctx_api, self.state_dispenser)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vkbottle/dispatch/views/abc/message.py", line 73, in handle_event
handler_response = await handler.handle(message, **context_variables)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vkbottle/dispatch/handlers/from_func_handler.py", line 32, in handle
return await self.handler(event, **acceptable_context)
File "/app/blueprints/images.py", line 43, in genimage
headline = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size = 30)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 959, in truetype
return freetype(font)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 956, in freetype
return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 247, in __init__
self.font = core.getfont(
OSError: cannot open resource
```

Фрагмент кода, где происходит работа с pillow:

```
img = Image.open('image.jpg')

        idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

        W, H = img.size
        w, h = idraw.textsize(textforimage)

        home = Path.home()
        font_path = Path(home, "blueprints", "arial.ttf")

        headline = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, size = 30)
        idraw.text(((W-w)/2,(H-h)/2), textforimage, font=headline)

        img.save('imageandtext.jpg')
```

Comment: Ну видимо на heroku просто не существует такого шрифта, закачайте сами

Comment: А как его добавить?